# doctrine does not keep the entity state when finding it again

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Within a single Unit Of Work I'm trying to do the following:

- I remove a specific entity
- I fetch it again by calling `EntityManager::findById()`
- I check its state by calling `$this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityState($item)`

What I get is a managed state in place of a removed one. Is that correct? I'm not finding any piece of information about this behavior.

**EDIT**

```
    $this->em->remove($varSelection);
    $en = $this->em->getRepository(VarSelection::class)->findOneById($varSelection->getId());
    dump($varSelection === $en //FALSE
```

`$varSelection` returns a state of Remove, while `$en` not. Plus, they are not the same object.

According to the [Doctrine's documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map), the “Identity Map” pattern should do the job, but apparently it does not.

Comment: Need to do a flush after the remove to get everything in sync.

Comment: @Cerad that's exactly what I do not want to do in order to save "flush" cycles! I think Doctrine should keep the state along with my operations until I flush it, and in case I try to find the same entity again the ORM should retrieve the same entity instance, already loaded in memory. Am I right? Am i not? You say I should flush, but I would like to know the whys of that in place of doing it

Comment: @Cerad http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look to the internals, you can notice this

```
public function scheduleForDelete($entity)
{
    $oid = spl_object_hash($entity);

    if (isset($this->entityInsertions[$oid])) {
        if ($this->isInIdentityMap($entity)) {
            $this->removeFromIdentityMap($entity);
        }
    [...]
}
```

This is called during `remove` operation, at some point. As you can understand, your object is no longer into the `IdentityMap` so next `findById` will retrieve a brand new object from db.

However `IdentityMap` works as you expect in general: if you query for an object (by id) that was inserted into `IdentityMap` before, you'll get back the same object; after a `remove` the behavior is what you noticed.

Honestly I don't know that much about Doctrine internals to explain why `remove` operation removes entity from `IdentityMap` but to answer your question

> What I get is a managed state in place of a removed one. Is that correct?

yes, this seems to be the correct behavior.

Comment: This is actually a functionality under discussion. Here is the test reproducing the behavior https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/6126

Comment: @Bertuz thank you for the news (btw I was subscribed to GitHub discussion already, but this could be helpful for those who are not)